# jQuery body:not() not working

Tags: jquery, html, click, slide, slidetoggle

I want to slideToggle the `#display` div by clicking `#button` div and also slideUp the `#display` div by clicking on the body But  when I will click on `#display` div it will not slideUp.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#button").click(function(event){
                    $("#display").slideToggle("1000");
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });

                $("body").not("#display").click(function(){
                    $("#display").slideUp("1000");
                });

            });
```

```css
#display {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    width:800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    padding: 50px;
}

#button {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    display: block;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click here</button>
        <div id="display">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas inlit fugit dolor soluta, doloribus dignissimos nobis deserunt a rerum ea! Ut repudiandae, repellat sed ad inventore cum amet reiciendis ipsum! Dolor.
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#button").click(function(event){
                    $("#display").slideToggle("1000");
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });

                $("body").not("#display").click(function(){
                    $("#display").slideUp("1000");
                });
      $('#display').click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
      });

            });
```

```css
#display {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    width:800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    padding: 50px;
}

#button {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    display: block;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click here</button>
        <div id="display">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas inlit fugit dolor soluta, doloribus dignissimos nobis deserunt a rerum ea! Ut repudiandae, repellat sed ad inventore cum amet reiciendis ipsum! Dolor.
        </div>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

`.not()` is not what you want to use here. What that would do is return every body element whose ID is not display. What you should do instead is make it a normal body click event, then check if the id of what you clicked is display within that, so it won't just affect body elements:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function(event){
        $("#display").slideToggle("1000");
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $("body").click(function(event){
        if (event.target.id != "display") {
            $("#display").slideUp("1000");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, it also works nicely. happy to get help from you. good luck :)